# BufferedReader does not work well

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

Loading following URL with `BufferedReader`, but content is not delivered. Even though a plain browser can show content. So `str` will remain nil. Any idea why?

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=zorr&y=&plot=short&r=json");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {}
Log.d("alma", str);
```

[image]

Comment: Your loop does nothing except consume the input and throw it away, and then exits when `str` becomes null. So it's null. What exactly were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring all of the lines that you are reading. You then exit the loop when `str` becomes `null`. So, your `Log.d()` call will always show `null`.

If you want to use the lines that you are reading, use `str` *inside*` your currently empty block:

```
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
  // do something with str
}
```

You might also wish to consider using a third-party library that offers a simpler API. OkHttp3, for example, makes getting a string response from a URL [fairly easy](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#synchronous-get).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=zorr&y=&plot=short&r=json");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
   Log.d("alma", str); // this should be here
}
```